# When to terminate DB connection after nodejs task done?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I run `nodejs downloadData.js` in server side to make multiple nested async calls to save data to mongodb.

However, I would like to terminate the DB connection once the jobs are done. But where should I use `mongoose.connection.close()`?

If I leave the connection open, the command will not return in prompt and hang forever. Thus I considered to terminate the DB connection in the callback function, but there is no guarantee which callback is the last one.

The pseudocode in `downloadData.js` looks like:

```
//let's make 20 times async call;
var request = require('request'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    index = 0;
mongoose.connect(dbURL);

var makeAsyncCall = function() {    
        index++;
        request(dataToSave, function(err, response, body) {
        saveDataToMongoDB();
        if(index<20)
          makeAsyncCall();
        }   
    }

 makeAsyncCall();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var request = require('request'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        index = 0,
        max =20;
    mongoose.connect(dbURL);

    var makeAsyncCall = function() {    
            index++;
            request(dataToSave, function(err, response, body) {
               saveDataToMongoDB(index);
               if(index<max)
                  makeAsyncCall();
           }  
        }
```

in saveDataToMongoDB(i)

check if 'i' is (max-1) then close connection in saveDataToMongoDB function

Comment: This wont work. `saveDataToMongoDB` is also async call. when DB connection is closed at `else` in your code. some of savetoDB actions are not returned, thus error throws - `error save to DB: MongoError: topology was destroyed`

Comment: Thanks, this cleared my thought. My case is slightly complicated than this pseudo code, I will test the code and mark your answer as solution.

Comment: This actually is the correct solution and I have implemented it succesfully, One more point to mention is that `closeDBConnection` has to be done in the callback function of `saveDataToMongoDB`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing as per my understanding. Create the connection for mongo in saveDataToMongoDB() and when data got inserted close the connection in callback, this will solve your issue.

Comment: it might not be good practice to frequently open and close connections. I prefer to maintain one connection only until everything is done in the task.